# gedit admin:// timeout

Tags: gvfs

Whenever I do some administration on my home server, I will have a terminal open running commands with `sudo` and modifying files with `gedit admin://<path_to_file> &!`

Since it always take me more than 5 minutes to get everything done, I found annoying to have to re-type my password every so often.

I successfully managed to increase the time-out for command line from the default 5 minutes to 1 hour by adding the following content in `/etc/sudoers.d/<custom_file>`:

> Defaults:<user>   timestamp_timeout=60

But I can't find a way to increase the time-out of gvfsd-admin and prevent the prompt for password so often (see screenshot here *- sorry it is in French*: [gvfsd-admin password prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRPAB.png))

I know there are workarounds like using `sudo -H gedit <file>` but it will come with other downsides.

Thank you.

Comment: I think, one simple solution would be to leave `gedit` running and not closing it before running the subsequent `gedit ...` commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, despite not closing `gedit`, the password prompt will still show up after like 5 minutes when saving the file, that's the point.